# How can I access props using the Vue 3 composition API?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to build a very simple component that just renders a string prop and logs the string prop on mount.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Prop: {{ typedProps.msgProp }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineProps, onMounted } from "vue";

interface IDemoProps {
  msgProp?: string;
}

export default {
  setup(props: IDemoProps) {
    const typedProps = defineProps({
      msgProp: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    });

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(typedProps)
    });

    return { typedProps };
  }
};
</script>
```

Currently `typedProps` is null both in the template and in the setup method? How can I configure the component to access the `msgProp` correctly? I also want to assign a type of `string` to the prop.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `setup script`.  This is recommended SFC approach.

1. you do not have to reference props from template.
2. you do not have to return props, includes, computed, etc. from script

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Prop: {{ msgProp }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, onMounted } from "vue";

interface IDemoProps {
  msgProp: string;
}

const props = defineProps<IDemoProps>();

onMounted(() => {
 console.log(props)
});
</script>
```